# Powershell process deleted user from Active directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a question regarding the following topic.
I get all the deleted users from active directory, and I want to test that a specific user is in this list.

Here is my code:

```
$deleted_users=get-adobject -SearchBase $domain -filter 'objectclass -eq "user" -AND IsDeleted -eq $True' -IncludeDeletedObjects -properties IsDeleted,LastKnownParent | Format-List Name,IsDeleted,LastKnownParent,DistinguishedName
    foreach($obj in $deleted_users){
      if($obj -like "$user*"){
        echo $obj
      }
    }
```

My problem is that even if the `$user` is in the `$deleted_users`, my if statement doesn't return it to me.

Can you tell me where is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Format-List` is for displaying data. Its output is not suitable for further processing. If you want to further process a selection of the objects' properties, use `Select-Object` instead:

```
$deleted_users = Get-ADObject ... | Select-Object Name, IsDeleted, ...
```

Then filter the list for a particular name like this:

```
$deleted_users | ? { $_.Name -like "$user*" }
```